# Haskell: function to accept random Int

Tags: haskell, random

I have a basic function that accepts an Int and returns a list:

```
generateCode rnd = 
  [sharpOrDot i rnd  | i <- [0..24]]
```

I call it from my main function like this:

```
do
  r  <- (randomIO :: IO Int)
  generateCode r
```

Shouldn't `r  <- (randomIO :: Int)` "unpack" the `Int` part from `IO Int` and hence just pass a Int to generateCode?

It returns the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `[Char]'
```

Thanks

Comment: The type signature is incorrect - it should be `randomIO :: IO Int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the last line must be `return (generateCode r)`. Else your `do`-block would "break out" of the `IO` monad, which is impossible (well, without using the function with the name we don't dare to speak out).